# setting nested virtualization in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, windows-10, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu as my host machine and using KVM.
In my KVM machine (windows guest) I have installed Vmware.

Is it possible to run machines inside the windows guest (in the vmware)
I know is it related to nested virtualization, tried few things i read on internet but none of them worked. I will glad if you know how to solve this issue.
Thanks